# Regex, php и \\

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
<?php
function no_slashes($str){
    $pattern = "/[\\]/i";
    $replacement = '';
    $str=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
    return $str;
}
echo no_slashes("\\");
```

Этот код должен убирать слеши, но выводится ошибка
Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 3 in C:\localhost\file.php on line 5. Что не так с кодом?

Comment: [`stripslashes`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stripslashes.php) уже изобретен. Также если не требуется иной логики - то проще использовать `str_replace`.

Comment: Обратные слеши нужно экранировать, то есть у вас должно быть `"/[\\\\]/i"`.

Comment: @u_mulder `echo stripslashes('foo\\\\bar');` немного не то

Answer (score 1):

Штука в том, что обратный слэш имеет особое значение в php и особое значение в регулярках.

Запустите интерактивный пхп (из консоли `php -a`)  и введите:

```
echo  "\\";
```

Как видите пхп вывел только один слэш. Дело в том, что слэш в этом контексте это экранирующий символ и чтобы он не был экранирующим символом, надо его экранировать :-)

В регулярке слэш тоже экранирующий символ и вы совершенно справедливо написали `\\`. Но только `\\` превратится `\` во время парсинга строки и в функцию preg_replace попадёт `/[\]/i` (то есть экранированная скобка). Чтобы этого избежать надо экранировать оба слэша: `/[\\\\]/i`.

Попробуйте в консоли

```
echo "/[\\\\]/i";
```

---

Обратите внимание, что для простой замены символа (или набора символов) можно использовать и другие функции php: [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php), [substr_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.substr-replace.php), [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php).

А если вы всё-таки хотите использовать регулярки, то тут вам не нужен символьный класс (квадратные скобки) и нечувствительность к регистру (i), можно просто написать `/\\\\/`.